# Output video with 6 ch audio to HDMI stereo

Tags: audio, hdmi

I use RPi as a media player with raspbian and omxplayer.

My hardware system: RPi ->[HDMI]-> Sony Bravia TV ->[Audio Cable]-> Microlab Stereo.

I have a problem with 6 channel audio: voice is very silent. It seems that center channels used for voice in 5.1 audio, and my stereo system just has no these channels.

Is there a way for playing such video with normalized sound on RPi?